# I am having trouble getting my function to provide its output in a matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, output

I want to plot the log of a variable `Dl` which depends on a variable `z` with respect to `log(z)`. I'm trying to do this for `z = 1:100` but it returns only 1 number for `Dl`.

```
% Log(Dl) versus Log(Redshift)
m = 1;
d = 0;
z = linspace(1,100,1);
Dl = zeros(1,100);
for z = 1:100
    [Dl,Da] = Cosmological(m,d,z);
end
y = log(Dl);
x = log(1:100);
plot(x,y)
```

apologies for any silly or useless lines of code I'm very new to programming. The function `cosmological` that I called for is written as follows (but there are no errors so may not be necessary, I'm posting just in case):

```
function [Dl,Da] = Cosmological(m,d,z)
f = @(x)1./((1+x).*((m.*(1+z)-m+d.*((1+x).^(-2))-d+1).^(.5)));
q = integral(f,0,z);   % Integral part equations for Dl
if m+d==1             % flat universe condition
    Dl=c/H0.*(1+z)*q;
elseif m+d<1          %positive spatial curvature universe condition
    Dl=c/H0*(1-m-d)^(-1/2)*(1+z)*sinh((1-m-d)^.5).*q;
else                  % negative spatial curvature universe condition
    Dl=c/H0*(1-m-d)^(-1/2)*(1+z)*sin((1-m-d)^.5).*q;
end
Da = Dl/(1+z)^2;       %Angular diameter distance function
end
```

Answer (score 1):

First, these line is not needed, you assign `z` with `1:100` in the loop:

```
z = linspace(1,100,1);
```

You get only one value because your loop saves only the last value. You should index `Dl` with `z` like this (and probably also `Da`):

```
for z = 1:100
    [Dl(z),Da] = Cosmological(m,d,z);
end
```